# Upload image to firebase with React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, github, react-native, upload

I have tried to follow this tutorial: https://github.com/CodeLinkIO/Firebase-Image-Upload-React-Native

but got stuck in RNFB_ANDROID_PERMISSIONS=true react-native link

This command crashed my application and I cannot continue anymore. Is there any other good tutorial to do this?

Comment: That command should link the dependencies to the project for you. You should post details on how the app is actually crashing. This is too little information to go on.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this command inside the console in Windows? The command sets the env variable and then runs `react-native link`, so the issue could be that you are just not setting the env variable right.
The following post should might help 
https://superuser.com/questions/212150/how-to-set-env-variable-in-windows-cmd-line